# google map - Zoom and Centering not working

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, zooming, centering

I am sure it is something very simple and a silly mistake on my end but for the life of me I can not get my zoom or set center to work.  Please can someone point out my mistake.  I have read and tried everything I could find to fix this.

url: http://www.justawebbie.freehostingcloud.com/test-map4.html

thank you for  your time.

Comment: What's wrong? It looks fine to me.

Answer (score 7):

This is the best zoom for your map:

```
map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(64.85599578876611, -147.83363628361917));
map.setZoom(15);
```

Comment: this worked for me, thank you thank you Broady, I see it was my LatLng was off I guess I find something else to use to grab those. Thank you really Broady your help is so much appreciated.

Comment: No problem! I used the "Drop LatLng marker" lab on Google maps. Could you please accept the answer? :)

Answer (score 2):

I added **setZoom(11)** after **map.fitBounds(bounds)**. It worked for me.
Try it.

```
setMarkers(map)
    {
        var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
        for(var i=0;i<this.markers.length;i++)
        {
            bounds.extend(this.markers[i].getPosition());
            map.setCenter(this.markers[i].getPosition())
            map.fitBounds(bounds);
            map.setZoom(11);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your map shows [the right viewport](http://maps.google.com/?q=64.8504701658,-147.856123924&z=14) for the only `setCenter()` and `setZoom()` calls I see, which are equivalent to passing options to the `Map` constructor:

```
google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
  zoom: 14,
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(64.8504701658,-147.856123924),
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I got same issue. maybe google map have some bugs/issues with load tiles. I added a delay and set it myself.

```
setTimeout(() => {
      this.map.setZoom(zoom);
}, 3000);
```